# Please create a tag for Spellfire

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I am a new user to this Stack Exchange site (although I have been an active user on other SE sites for many years). I had wanted to ask a rules question about the collectible card game [Spellfire, Master the Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellfire), but it seems there is no existing tag for it. I believe Spellfire was the second CCG created after MTG (but was discontinued in the 90s), so I'm a little surprised there is no tag for it already.

As a new user, I don't have enough to rep to create a new tag myself. Could someone possibly create a tag for Spellfire?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, we can only create tags by adding them to questions, and up till today [there aren't any Spellfire questions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search?q=spellfire). Please ask your actual question on the main site, using any other tag (even if it's not really applicable). It's best to leave a comment asking for the tag to be created.

Once somebody else creates the tag, it's recommended to create a [tag excerpt](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts) for it; otherwise, [it might get cleaned up after six months](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/487/12315).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice. I posted my question here: [Who can cast spells during combat in Spellfire?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/57456/who-can-cast-spells-during-combat-in-spellfire). It seems you already created the Spellfire tag - thanks for that!